# Magento 2: Clear collection cache on category create

Tags: magento2, cache

I am looking for a way to clear the collection cache on category create event programmatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the below code with your code observing the event

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface $typeListInterface
) {
    $this->cacheTypeList = $typeListInterface;
}

public function clearCollectionCache()
{
    $this->cacheTypeList->cleanType(\Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\Collection::TYPE_IDENTIFIER);
}
```